# Animation between content levels in AngularJS webapp

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs, interface

I am building a functionality for the web app we are working on. App is running on AngularJS 1.0.7

The functionality is following:
User can navigate the app quite conventionally, drilling down into levels of content. One ng-view, several controllers with more controllers and partials inside.

[image: regular state]

In 4 first levels of the content, user has ability to see the 'path' (same as breadcrumbs):
[image: Overview opened]

Here is where things become interesting. When user clicks on one of the levels, that level will expand and the content of that level will be inside it. The originally opened content will slide down:
[image]

As a reference to understand it better, think of Evernote's mobile app. There, you use the same mechanism to switch between views that are on the same level, so every level can be represented by a controller in one parent.

In my case, however, all 4 levels are in hierarchical structure. On level 1 you have option to see several level 2's, on level 2 you can go to several different level 3's.

I am trying to see how to make it possible. I need to keep previous and new content visible during the transition.

Answer (score 0):

**In the end, I implemented that functionality with clever use of dummy elements.**

When navigation was triggered:

- Container element was duplicated and replaced the actual content
- Actual container was moved off screen
- Animation was started to transition dummy element off screen and actual content area to its place